# How to do Pivoting in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pivot, postgresql-9.1

I am new to PostgreSQL.

Suppose I have a table as under

```
colorname   Hexa    rgb rgbvalue
Violet  #8B00FF r   139
Violet  #8B00FF g   0
Violet  #8B00FF b   255
Indigo  #4B0082 r   75
Indigo  #4B0082 g   0
Indigo  #4B0082 b   130
Blue    #0000FF r   0
Blue    #0000FF g   0
Blue    #0000FF b   255
```

If I do a Pivot in SQL Server as

```
SELECT colorname,hexa,[r], [g], [b]
FROM
(SELECT colorname,hexa,rgb,rgbvalue
    FROM tblPivot) AS TableToBePivoted
PIVOT
(
sum(rgbvalue)
FOR rgb IN ([r], [g], [b])
) AS PivotedTable;
```

I get the output as

```
colorname   hexa    r   g   b
Blue    #0000FF 0   0   255
Indigo  #4B0082 75  0   130
Violet  #8B00FF 139 0   255
```

How to do the same using PostgreSQL?

My attempt is

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab
(
    'SELECT 
        colorname
        ,hexa
        ,rgb
        ,rgbvalue
    FROM tblPivot'
)AS ct(colorname text, hexa text, rgb text, rgbvalue int);
```

But geting error:

```
ERROR:  function crosstab(unknown) does not exist
LINE 2: FROM crosstab
             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********
ERROR: function crosstab(unknown) does not exist**
```

Is there any elegant way of doing so in PostgreSQL (any built in function...) What is the standard practice of doing so ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be expressed as a JOIN:

```
SELECT c.colorname, c.hexa, r.rgbvalue, g.rgbvalue, b.rgbvalue
FROM (SELECT colorname, hexa
      FROM sometable
      GROUP BY colorname) c
JOIN sometable r ON c.colorname = r.colorname AND r.rgb = 'r'
JOIN sometable g ON c.colorname = g.colorname AND g.rgb = 'g'
JOIN sometable b ON c.colorname = b.colorname AND b.rgb = 'b'
;
```

Comment: But why crosstab didnot work... does it not support in the current version that I am using?

Comment: `crosstab()` belongs to the `tablefunc` module.  You will have to enable it using `CREATE EXTENSION`.  That said; the convenience it offers may not be that great; postgresql is fantastically good at optimizing joins, and this sort of code will be more recognizable across more databases and to more developers.

Comment: If you do a LOT of crosstab stuff, the tablefunc contrib module can be great.  If you're on Ubuntu, you can add tablefunc functions to a db by doing this: psql dbname -f /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/tablefunc.sql  or something similar.

Comment: I "think" first line should be "SELECT c.colorname, c.hexa, r.rgbvalue, g.rgbvalue, b.rgbvalue" instead, but otherwise +1 for this answer.

Answer (score 56):

Run this

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

and try to execute your query

Comment: if I run this I get `ERROR:  extension "tablefunc" already exists` but when I try to use it I get `ERROR:  function crosstab(unknown) does not exist`.  I'm using Postgres 9.2.1 on Mac 10.9.2.  Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you are connected to your database with \c db_name and then run the command above.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23073241/177116) has answer to the question raised in the @Black's comment.